# GruntJS running multiple tasks and forewarding arguments

Tags: javascript, build-automation, gruntjs

I'm using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) and have a "build" and a "clean" task. The former accepts a list of arguments.

Now I want to create a "rebuild" task, that first runs "clean" and then runs "build", forwarding any arguments it got to "build".

I did not find anything in the [Grunt API docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task) indicating this can be done via the Geunt API, so ended up doing this:

```
grunt.task.registerTask(
        'rebuild',
        'Run clean followed by build with the provided arguments',
        function() {
            grunt.task.run([
                'clean',
                ['build'].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)).join(":")
            ]);
        }
    );
```

While this works, I'd rather use something build into Grunt if available. Does grunt support this somehow?

Comment: what if you write `['clean', 'build'.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)).join(":")]`?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: this just saves me two brackets - or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: ops sorry. didn't noticed an open square bracket :(